# The type 'CLIMutable' is not defined when I attempt to run FAKE's build.cmd on Windows

Tags: f#, f#-fake

I forked and cloned the [FAKE - F# Make Github Repo](https://github.com/fsharp/FAKE) so that I could potentially contribute back to it. I followed the [contributing instructions here](http://fsharp.github.io/FAKE/contributing.html). However, I almost immediately hit a snag. When I run build.cmd I receive the following errors.

```
1) Building ./FAKE.Deploy.Web.sln failed with exitcode 1.
2) FS0039: C:\Development\FAKE\src\deploy.web\Fake.Deploy.Web.Abstractions\AccountModels.fs(9,3): The type 'CLIMutable' is not defined
3) FS0039: C:\Development\FAKE\src\deploy.web\Fake.Deploy.Web.Abstractions\AccountModels.fs(17,3): The type 'CLIMutable' is not defined
4) FS0039: C:\Development\FAKE\src\deploy.web\Fake.Deploy.Web.Abstractions\AccountModels.fs(30,3): The type 'CLIMutable' is not defined
5) FS0039: C:\Development\FAKE\src\deploy.web\Fake.Deploy.Web.Abstractions\AccountModels.fs(37,3): The type 'CLIMutable' is not defined
6) FS0039: C:\Development\FAKE\src\deploy.web\Fake.Deploy.Web.Abstractions\Model.fs(9,3): The type 'CLIMutable' is not defined
7) FS0039: C:\Development\FAKE\src\deploy.web\Fake.Deploy.Web.Abstractions\Model.fs(16,3): The type 'CLIMutable' is not defined
8) FS0039: C:\Development\FAKE\src\deploy.web\Fake.Deploy.Web.Abstractions\Model.fs(36,3): The type 'CLIMutable' is not defined
9) FS0039: C:\Development\FAKE\src\deploy.web\Fake.Deploy.Web.Abstractions\Model.fs(64,3): The type 'CLIMutable' is not defined
10) FS0039: C:\Development\FAKE\src\deploy.web\Fake.Deploy.Web.Abstractions\Model.fs(70,3): The type 'CLIMutable' is not defined
```

I have Visual Studio 2012 which comes with F# 3.0. I confirmed that the F# SDK is installed by running `System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` in the F# interactive window. The result was `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\F#\3.0\Framework\v4.0\`.

From what I have found F# 3.0 introduced the CLIMutable attribute. I made no modifictions to the source code between cloning it and running the build.

I opened the FAKE.Web.Deploy solution and inspected where the references. The FSharp.Core.dll appears to be built against F# 4.3.1 which I do not have. I suspect this may be part of the problem. This version would appear to come with Visual Studio 2013. I could download Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition but is it possible to get the latest version of F# for Visual Studio 2012?

Is this even the problem?
What else might be wrong?

Comment: Check `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\FSharp\.NETFramework\v4.0` for the appropriate version of FSharp.Core.dll

Comment: The path does not exist on my machine. I have `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\FSharp\3.0\Runtime\v4.0` which appears to be 4.3.0.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon further inspection the issue seems to be that several of the F# projects in the repo did not have the necessary library references. Specifically, as of commit 8df8a2f the following were missing.

- From Fake.Deploy.Web.fsproj

  - FSharp.Core.dll
- From Fake.Deploy.Web.Abstractions

  - FSharp.Core.dll
- From Fake.Deploy.Web.RavenDb.fsproj

  - FSharp.Core.dll
  - FSharp.Data.TypeProviders

NuGet had already pulled down the FSharp.Core.dll so I only had to add the reference to the affected projects. FSharp.Data.TypeProviders.dll was not already downloaded but I was able to use NuGet to quickly fix that issue as well.